# Java generate random number based on boxplot

Tags: java, statistics, boxplot, random

I'm searching for a method or library for java (can be java-8) that is capable of generating a random sample (preferable with a fixed seed for deterministic testing) based on the numbers that make up a boxplot.

So imagine having the boxplot:

```
      ----------
|-----|  |     |-----------|
      ----------
min   A avg    B          max
```

where you now the numbers `min`, `A`, `avg`, `B`, and `max`. The method or library should generate a random number that is bound with these rules.

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.Random#nextGaussian()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29

Comment: Unfortunately a boxplot is usually not a Gaussian distribution (it can be though, rarely). It's more like a skewed normal distribution

Comment: I know, that's why I'm saying "take a look" and don't post it as an answer. It is very simple to implement skewness and min-max filter to achieve what you need.

Comment: I disagree on the 'simple' part, that's why I asked the question here :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed that `min`, `a`, `median`, `b`, `max` values separate quartiles of distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile):

```
static public double next(Random rnd, double median, double a, double b, double min, double max) {
    double d = -3;
    while (d > 2.698 || d < -2.698) {
        d = rnd.nextGaussian();
    }
    if (Math.abs(d) < 0.6745) {
        if (d < 0) {
            return median - (median - a) / 0.6745 * (-d);  // 2nd quartile
        } else {
            return median + (b - median) / 0.6745 * d;  // 3rd quartile
        }
    } else {
        if (d < 0) {
            return a - (a - min) / (2.698 - 0.6745) * ((-d) - 0.6745);  // 1st quartile
        } else {
            return b + (max - b) / (2.698 - 0.6745) * (d - 0.6745);  // 4th quartile
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I discover in which quartile `d = rnd.nextGaussian()` gets into, and project the value to corresponding part of the given boxplot.

Comment: That is indeed the quartiles that I was referring to. Please give me some time to read through and understand the code before I accept this as answer though :).

Comment: @user3354890 I believe this picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile#mediaviewer/File:Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg would help to understand.

Comment: I read it, tried it, and it seems to be right :). Thank you very much.